# shared variable become NoneType after set the value in theano

Tags: theano

```
class sharedvariable_test:
    def __init__(self, sizes):
          self.param = [theano.shared(p)
                  for p in sizes]

    def update(self):
         temp_p = [None] * len(self.param)
         for i in range(len(self.param)):
              temp_p[i] = 1

         self.param = [p.set_value(tp)
                  for p, tp in zip(self.param, temp_p)]

         for p in self.param:
              print(p.get_value()) # error occurred here
```

after the function update, the shared variable in list self.param become NoneType, and the error message is "The NoneType has no attribute of get_value",and am I supposed to name the shared variable ? and not just put it into a list

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
self.param = [p.set_value(tw)
         for p, tw in zip(self.param, temp_w)]
```

is the reason that caused the error
and just to convert it to

```
for p, tw in zip(self.param, temp_w):
        p.set_value(tw)
```

will be alright